# export encrypted emails from lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes

I've got a bunch of encrypted old emails in a lotus notes database (nsf) file. I've also got my old .id file as well, therefore I managed to open the emails with a lotus notes client.

Is it possible to decrypt and export the emails to an open format using commonly available tools?

Answer (score 1):

I was sooooo tempted to just answer "yes" ;)

1. Make sure, that "encrypt incoming mail" (under File->Security->User Security->Mail) is deselected .
2. Create an Agent with the following commands "@Command([RefreshSelectedDocument]); @Command([DeselectAll])"
3. Use the .eml Export functionality of Notes 8.5.2 to either File->Export the selected Files to .eml files or just Drag & Drop the mails on your desktop.

HTH

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately RefreshSelectedDocument did not work. However, I found another function ToolsRefreshAllDocs, which did the trick.